# How to use variabled function with formatted string?

Tags: function, variables, formatted-input

I need to use my function as a variable but when I tried to use it with formatted string it print the variable ID, but when I use it like this -->

*dot = efdot*

*dot()*

It prints function. Here is my code I summarized it.

**code:**

```
import time

    def efdot():
        bar = "⦾⦿"
        index = 0
        while True:
            print(bar[index % len(bar)], end="\r")
            index += 1
            time.sleep(0.5)
    
    
    dot = efdot
    var = input(f"{dot}Hello World{dot}")
```

**output:**

```
<function efdot at 0x0000016EDCEF3E20>Hello World<function efdot at 0x0000016EDCEF3E20>
```

Comment: You should add the appropriate language tag. Although I suspect the solution will be simply to actually call the function with `dot()` inside your formatted string

Comment: Typo, and duplicate of "[Input response is not working as I expected \[closed\]](/q/58829234/90527)", "[In PyCharm not able to see the buttons using Tkinter](/q/68211018/90527)", "[file not closing](/q/9148106/90527)", and likely many others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call your function with the parentheses: `dot()`

```
import time

def efdot():
    bar = "⦾⦿"
    return bar

dot = efdot
var = input(f"{dot()}Hello World{dot()}")


⦾⦿Hello World⦾⦿
```

But because your function never ends with that infinite loop, it won't print the rest of the string.

Summary:

- You need to call the function in the string
- It won't work as you expected because of the infinite loop

Comment: I tried it but it only gives the function with the string.. function just print out in the terminal it doesn't blink up.